# Playwright chromium fonts doesn't work in production environment

Tags: fonts, chromium, playwright

I am generating an image using playwright through chromium. Fonts work perfectly fine when I generate it on my local machine. But when the same goes on prod environment inside an AWS EKS, the text is not correct.

Below is my launcher code

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
  timeout: 1200000
})
page = await browser.newPage();
let html = fs.readFileSync('assets/new_temp_2.html', 'utf8');
await page.setContent(html, {
  timeout: 1200000
})
await page.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
const elementHandle = await page.$('.content');

// get the bounding area where our questions is situated on page
let boundingRectangle = await elementHandle.boundingBox()

// Take a screenshot of the rendered math
await page.screenshot({
  fullPage: true,
  path: 'image.png'
  clip: {
    x: boundingRectangle.x,
    y: boundingRectangle.y,
    height: boundingRectangle.height,
    width: boundingRectangle.width
  }
})
```

I have tried the configs in args - https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Please help if you have got similar problem.